# Python script to delete all hidden object

Tags: python, objects, visibility

I found a script to delete all hidden object of my scene but it wont work.
I'm not an expert at this, at all, do anyone knows how to achieve that?

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.hide_viewport == True:
        obj.hide_viewport = False
        obj.select = True
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

thanks a lot :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy 

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.hide_viewport or o.hide_render or o.hide_get(): 
        bpy.data.objects.remove(o, do_unlink=True)
```

Note that this removes all objects in the file including other scenes than the active one. Also this removes objects with any one of these disabled [image] - hidden in the viewport(`hide_viewport`), objects hidden for render(`hide_render`) and objects disabled in viewports (`hide_get()`) whatever that means.

Comment: wow thanks a lot! Do you think it's possible to remove only the objects that are just hidden in the viewport (and not the hide_render and hide_get) ? 
Thanks again!!

Comment: Sure, just delete `or o.hide_render or o.hide_get()` in the if statement's condition.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot sir :)